# Jest Difference Between toBeCalledWith and toHaveBeenCalledWith

Tags: jestjs

This isn't obvious from the docs but... What is the difference between `toBeCalledWith` and `toHaveBeenCalledWith`?

Answer (score 48):

From the docs https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-

`.toHaveBeenCalledWith(arg1, arg2, ...)` under the alias: `.toBeCalledWith()`

From the source code:

https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/b7cb5221bb06b6fe63c1a5e725ddbc1aaa82d306/packages/expect/src/spyMatchers.ts#L1128

https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/b7cb5221bb06b6fe63c1a5e725ddbc1aaa82d306/packages/expect/src/spyMatchers.ts#L1131

```js
//...
  toBeCalledWith: createToBeCalledWithMatcher('toBeCalledWith'),
  toHaveBeenCalled: createToBeCalledMatcher('toHaveBeenCalled'),
  toHaveBeenCalledTimes: createToBeCalledTimesMatcher('toHaveBeenCalledTimes'),
  toHaveBeenCalledWith: createToBeCalledWithMatcher('toHaveBeenCalledWith'),
//...
```

They are created by the `createToBeCalledWithMatcher` function with only a different name.

So, they are the same.

**UPDATE:** Here is my personal understanding of why jestjs provide these matcher APIs aliases.

jestjs builds on `jasmine` test runner, see [Jasmine and Test Assertion Improvements](https://jestjs.io/blog/2016/04/12/jest-11#jasmine-and-test-assertion-improvements)

`jasmine` only provides a matcher - [toHaveBeenCalledWith](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html).

jestjs provides better matcher APIs over `jasmine`, The `toBeCalledWith` alias is shorter, easier to remember, and easier to use. There doesn't seem to be much semantic need for *"have been"*

Comment: Frankly, I'd expect `.toBeCalledWith()` to wait for the function to be called in the future in contract to `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` 